# why <li> is kept open without a </li> html nested lists

Tags: html

I posted a question and everyone said things that i was not really asking 
I will try to be more clear next time.

I was told that when nesting lists you must leave a `<li>` without a `</li>`

The <<<<<<<<<<<< point to the tags.

That is what i need someone to explain... I was told this is necessary and i can't find a resource that tells me why.

```
<ul>
<li> Louis </li>
<li> Louis <<<<<<<<<<<<<
<ol>
<li> Louis </li>
<li> Louis </li>
<ul> 
<li> Louis </li>
<li> Louis </li>
<ol>
<li> Louis </li>
 <li> Louis </li>
</ol>
</ul>
</ol>
</li> <<<<<<<<<<
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

A list of a list of *things*.

Each *thing* is represented by a list item.

The nested list is such a *thing*. It has to be part of a list item so that it can be in another list.

It might be easier to understand if you fix the errors in your example and indent it properly.

```css
li {
  background: #faa;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
li li {
  background: #afa;
}
li li li {
  background: #aaf;
}
li li li li {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Louis</li>
  <li>Louis
    <ol>
      <li>Louis</li>
      <li>Louis
        <ul>
          <li>Louis</li>
          <li>Louis
            <ol>
              <li>Louis</li>
              <li>Louis</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The end tag for a list item can always be omitted. [Some tags are simply optional in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-tag-omission). The element will be ended when the parser hits a end end tag for the list or a start tag for the next list item.